Azure DevOps Server - how to know the system directories on another server?
I'm using two different build servers, one for builds with static code analysis, one without, to build some large Windows solutions.
Building on the two servers works perfectly well, but after that's done, I need the artifacts on one server. There's quite a bit of built-in functionality to deal with artifacts, but I would very much prefer a direct file copy instead.
It works if I hard-code the directories like \\server1\DevOpsAgent\_work\1\b\, but I will have a problem if the directory is not "1", or if the server name changes (I'm selecting servers via agent demands only).
Is there a way, at runtime, to find which directories the "other" server is using?
Haven't found an answer in the Microsoft documentation, or online.

TL;DR use pipeline artifacts (or, as an alternative, Universal Packages) instead of a direct file copy.

... I need the artifacts on one server. There's quite a bit of built-in functionality to deal with artifacts, but I would very much prefer a direct file copy instead.

I honestly don't see how using a direct file copy would simplify things, specially considering the issues you are already facing - using demands on agents, paths that might (and probably will) change, among others.
Also, you're trying to reinvent the wheel by using a workaround to solve a problem that was already solved a long, long time ago by the many CI/CD platforms out there: publishing and consuming artifacts between pipelines.
Using pipeline artifacts
Most of the cases using pipeline artifacts is quite simple - the publish pipeline generates artifacts into a folder, copy these files into a staging directory (optional) and then publish these artifacts:
# Generate artifacts into the $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) folder
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: 'p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" ...
    platform: 'Any CPU'
    configuration: 'Release'

# Publish files from $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) folder as artifacts
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    artifactName: WebApp

The consuming pipeline/stage/job downloads the artifacts and then uses them to deploy applications, run a script, etc
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    artifact: WebApp
    targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    # other properties here
    packageForLinux: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip'


you are absolutely right, using the built-in functions to publish artifacts makes life a lot easier.  We are using DevOps Server, and using PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to a network file path makes it very simple to copy to a network directory.
But how can I publish to another agent on a different machine during a DevOps run?

You don't publish artifacts to another agent - you publish artifacts to Azure DevOps or a file share, and then in the consumer pipeline you download these artifacts as specified in the first link of my answer. Please read the documentation carefully.

Just to be clear, artifacts are not not tied/coupled to a build agent or server. They will be published to Azure DevOps (ideally) or a file share that is accessible by any other build agent. Just like a nuget or npm feed where one pipeline can publish a package and another pipeline can build an application using that same package, without knowing any details about the pipeline or agent that published that package.

using PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to a network file path makes it very simple to copy to a network directory. But how can I publish to another agent on a different machine during a DevOps run? - not sure if I understand the last sentence - you mean how to download the artifacts in another build? It depends on how you configure your pipeline. Please edit your question and show us how you publish the artifacts.
